# Adding keywords/ tags to received e-mails in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, tags

Is it possible to add my own keywords/ tags to a received e-mail from within Outlook 2010? It would be nice if the changes were sync'd to the Exchange Server, so if/ when my PC dies, the modifications are maintained.

The reason is for specific searching over large quantities of e-mail...

Thanks,
Kieron

Answer (score 10):

I have only just started with Outlook 2010, but it appears that I can still do what I used to do in Outlook 2003.  On a received email, I add my keywords to the subject line, then press escape and save the email when prompted.

For instance, the subject line was "Re: in training".   I change that to "JIGSAW   |||   Re: in training".   The caps and the vertical lines tell me that it's something I added (and I can take that off if by chance I want to re-use the email), plus the caps make it easy to spot in a list.

This saved my life in a previous job where I had about 1200 subfolders in Outlook.  Plus it's searchable.

Comment: +1 Love this! Didn't realize you could do that without saving a copy of the item.

Answer (score 3):

Would the coloured categories (suitably renamed) do that for you, or do you have too many tags?

Answer (score 2):

I am using Outlook 2010. But I see this actually a missing feature.

1. Categories in outlook 2010 doesn't provide you the flexibilities of creating, assigning tags in handy way.
2. Assigned categories will be sent out together with email. Definitely sometime tags are 'personal' information and not appropriate to make public.
3. Change subject could be one solution, but face the same issue as mentioned in #2.
4. Categories is not designed to work with large numbers of items, say 100 more or less will messy the list box.

Search in outlook 2010 is need perfect in terms of user experience but outlook does lack one friendly, efficiently tagging feature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. I suggest you to use advanced find in outlook. More info [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-search-emails-outlook-2007/).